# Convert IEnumerable to HTML table string

Tags: c#, .net

My code can generate HTML table strings well, but it depends on JSON.NET.

I'm converting `IEnumerable` to an HTML table string using Json.NET but I think I shouldn't.

```
void Main()
{
    var datas = new[] { new {Name="Test"} };
    var array = datas.ToArray().ToHtmlTable(); //Run Success
    var set = datas.ToHashSet().ToHtmlTable();//Run Succes
    var list = datas.ToList().ToHtmlTable(); //Run Succes
    var enums = datas.AsEnumerable().ToHtmlTable(); //Run Succes
}

public static class HTMLTableHelper
{
    public static string ToHtmlTable(this IEnumerable enums)
    {
        return ToHtmlTableConverter(enums);
    }

    public static string ToHtmlTable(this System.Data.DataTable dataTable)
    {
        return ConvertDataTableToHTML(dataTable);
    }

    private static string ToHtmlTableConverter(object enums)
    {
        var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(enums);
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(jsonStr);
        var html = ConvertDataTableToHTML(data);
        return html;
    }

    private static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(System.Data.DataTable dt)
    {
        var html = new StringBuilder("<table>");

        //Header
        html.Append("<thead><tr>");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            html.Append("<th>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th>");
        html.Append("</tr></thead>");

        //Body
        html.Append("<tbody>");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                html.Append("<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>");
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        html.Append("</tbody>");
        html.Append("</table>");
        return html.ToString();
    }
}
```

I think it is bad because `SerializeObject` to string could be `DeserializeObject` to `DataTable` is a waste of efficiency.

```
var jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(enums);
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(jsonStr);
```

I want to remove dependencies on JSON.NET because it can reduce the size of the library.

Do you think I should replace them with something else if there is a better way?

Comment: mhmm... and yet you're using both `JsonNet` and `DataTable`s :-| Could you reframe your question please? Currently this is very confusing.

Comment: oh, I was afraid you might say that _but I don't know how to do it_ - we cannot help you with that because this is not a code writing site and we're not implementing new features or request.

Comment: Sorry,should I ask to StackOverflow? @t3chb0t

Comment: I don't think anybody would help you with that anywhere...

Comment: @t3chb0t: others may not write the code for him, but they could still point him in the right direction...

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Witvoet thanks, yes, i just hope someone point right direction

Comment: @ITWeiHan: read up on reflection. Also, Json.NET is open-source, so you can take a look at how `DeserializeObject` is implemented.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet as a matter of fact this could be even a valid Code Review question if asked differently... IT WeiHan you may usk us what we think of the JsonNet and DataTable dependency and why you think it's bad and what alternatives there might be or in which way would we improve that? I think this would be good question. But you have to tell us your reasoning etc. Simply saying I cannot use it is not enough.

Comment: @t3chb0t , thanks , I try to fix my qeustion.

Comment: I made a couple small changes to your question so it doesn't sound like _please implement something else for me_ any more - I hope like the edit ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t , thanks a lot !! I also trying search reflection docs now.Try to solve the problem.

Comment: @t3chb0t , Pieter Witvoet , thanks a lot,I do it!

Comment: You might want to check out T4 templates. You can come up with a more structured solution using that. Here is the link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can use reflection to solve it:

```
void Main()
{
    var datas = new[] { new {Name="Test1",Value="Test2"} };
    var array = datas.ToArray().ToHtmlTable(); //Run Success
    var set = datas.ToHashSet().ToHtmlTable();//Run Succes
    var list = datas.ToList().ToHtmlTable(); //Run Succes
    var enums = datas.AsEnumerable().ToHtmlTable(); //Run Succes
}

public static class HTMLTableHelper
{
    public static string ToHtmlTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enums)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var props = type.GetProperties();
        var html = new StringBuilder("<table>");

        //Header
        html.Append("<thead><tr>");
        foreach (var p in props)
            html.Append("<th>" + p.Name + "</th>");
        html.Append("</tr></thead>");

        //Body
        html.Append("<tbody>");
        foreach (var e in enums)
        {
            html.Append("<tr>");
            props.Select(s => s.GetValue(e)).ToList().ForEach(p => {
                html.Append("<td>" + p + "</td>");
            }); 
            html.Append("</tr>");
        }

        html.Append("</tbody>");
        html.Append("</table>");
        return html.ToString();
    }
}
```

```html
<table><thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Value</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>Test1</td><td>Test2</td></tr></tbody></table>
```